# How to fix overlay for block with position as sticky

Tags: html, css

The element sticks to the top, but with scrolling there is an overlay. How to fixed block with button without same overlay.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: #3989c9; position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0;">
    <p>text</p>
    <div style="margin: 10px;"><input id="btn_transfer_checkbox" type="button" value="Перенести"> 
</div>
</div>


<div>
    <div class="wrapper">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give it a `z-index` higher than the other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comment by Alon Eitan.

You need a `position` like `sticky` and `z-index` higher than the other elements. And you don't forget about `background` value.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 5px;
    max-width: min-content;
}

.header_library{
    background: #ffffff; 
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 80px;  
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

.row{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<div class="header_library">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Выберите плейлист или несколько и нажмите кнопку</p>
      <div style="margin: 10px;">
       <input id="btn_transfer_checkbox" type="button" value="Перенести">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input id="btn_checked_all" type="button" value="Выбрать все">
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    Some elements
</div>
```